# OpenGL ES: Multiple Meshes in one VBO

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

If I have multiple meshes in a single VBO, is there a way to apply transformations to those meshes independently?

If I call glDrawElements while a VBO with two meshes is bound, it's going to draw those two meshes with whatever the current MVP matrix is.  So if I have upwards of 20 independently moving meshes on the screen at a time, would I need 20 VBOs?  Or is there some way of specifying an offset and a count to glDrawElements so that it only renders the first mesh stored in the VBO?  This way I could change the MVP Matrix and then render the second mesh in the VBO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have three meshes with 5, 11 and 13 triangles respectively packed into one index buffer, you can draw the two separate meshes as:

```
// assumes index buffer has been bound
// set modelview
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 5 * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
// set modelview
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 11 * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 5 * 3 * sizeof(unsigned short));
// set modelview
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 13 * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (5 + 11) * 3 * sizeof(unsigned short));
```

You specify the offset by offsetting the pointer in the last argument.

Comment: Won't that limit you to just two meshes then?  For example, if I had 3 meshes and I wanted to transform the second one without affecting the others, I'm not sure how I'd do that.  The offset would get me to the start of the second mesh, but how would I tell it to stop before affecting the third one?

Comment: @Legion Well, when drawing the second one you, of course, well, only draw the second one and not, well, the second one and the third one.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck Of course! The second parameter is my count/size. Thanks!